# Ag Grid's React Column Filter not getting displayed as expected

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Without any change in the UI Component, my AG Grid's Filter changes from

[Filter when deploying the original code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiwL1.png)
to [Filter when deploying the new code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxVlD.png). There is a change in UI. However both the filters are still doing the same job.

What could be the reason for that ?

Answer explaining why this change is coming

Comment: looks like you've changed the theme for the grid?

Comment: No I haven't changed the theme. On clicking on any row, there's a popup coming. I have changed the code of that popup.